# GA4 Active Users for Today is not correct

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm currently working on migrating UA to GA4. I'm noticing an inconsistency in the data returned by the GA4 site/api for the "Active users today" value. Our properties that support GTM are reporting to both services right now, so I am using one of those as an example. I only get two meterics: current users (realtime) and today's users. Here are some current values from the API.

```
UA Current: 5
UA Today: 92
GA4 Current: 17
GA4 Today: 16
```

The difference in the two current values is okay because I'm reporting 15 minutes in GA4, while UA did only 5. The active users today value from UA seems correct, but the one from GA is obviously not right. Not only because it doesn't match, but because the value for today (currently 10 hours in) is even less than the value for the last 15 minutes!

I don't think the issue is due to incorrect usage of the API, because the same data is on analytics site:

- [GA4 Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG0PW.png)
- [UA Today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzAY4.png)

Any insights into why this would be an issue?
Does GA4 just really lag on processing today's day in a report compared to UA?

Joel

My report request is pretty simple:

```
RunReportRequest rrr = new RunReportRequest
{
    DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { new DateRange { StartDate = "today", EndDate = "today" } },
    Metrics = new List<Metric> { new Metric { Name = "activeUsers" } },
};
```

Comment: Have you checked https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en